# Periodic NullReferenceExceptions in EntityFramework where never should

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Every so often, maybe a couple of days per month, we are getting frequent errors with Entity Framework for our internal Line of Business application. These errors are primarily NullReferenceException within our code. These errors happen frequently for about a day, then go away for a couple weeks or so. We have found that restarting IIS can make them go away until next time. They do not happen on every request, but a non-trivial number. This kind of error we very rarely if ever see for a while, then will see a bunch throughout the day. I have not been able to correlate the timing with anything else going on with the server - either user activity or on the server itself.

All references to DbContext *should* be properly enclosed in a Using statement.

The errors typically seem to be in calling something like

```
var firstEntitiy = context.EntityA.Where(e => e.Id == itemId).Single();
var foreignName = firstEntity.EntityB.Name;

return foreignName;
```

Error seems to be on call to EntityB.Name. I know that there is a record for EntityA. And it has a non-nullable foreign key to EntityB, so don't know how EntityB could be null.

In addition to the standard NullReferenceException errors, we also will sometimes get EntityFramework.dll.ValidateRowsAffected or EntityFramework.dll.GetOtherEndOfRelationship errors during the same time frame.

This is something we've been dealing with for some time now. I've only ever seen it in Production, so have limited access to diagnose or debug.

Entity Framework 6.1.3 .Net 4.5.2. Sql Server 2012. Windows Server 2008

EDIT: Usually stack trace isn't helpful. Sometimes we do get exception in the framework itself.

```
Type : System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
Message : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source : EntityFramework
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd GetOtherEndOfRelationship(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.IEntityWrapper)
HResult : -2147467261
Stack Trace : at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.GetOtherEndOfRelationship(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.AddRelationshipDetectedByForeignKey(Dictionary`2 relationships, Dictionary`2 principalRelationships, EntityKey relatedKey, EntityEntry relatedEntry, RelatedEnd relatedEndFrom)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.DetectChangesInForeignKeys()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChangesInForeignKeys(IList`1 entries)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectStateManager.DetectChanges()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Add(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Add(TEntity entity)
```

Comment: `I know that there is a record for EntityA. And it has a non-nullable foreign key to EntityB` <= Query the db to find orphaned records or records where the value is null. It has to be one of those 2 because otherwise there would be an entity returned. Alternatively it could be you are using lazy loading but the dbcontext is disposed.

Comment: do you know exact stacktrace and code lines?

Comment: Also I am not a fan of lazy loading, my preference is to turn this off and to always explicitly define what you want returned. This will ensure less chances of performance issues due to code side effects like iterating over a returned list and reading related entities each of which might be lazy loaded from the DB. You can still explicitly request the child entity by using `Include` even when lazy loading is turned on. Example: `var firstEntitiy = context.EntityA.Include(x => x.EntityB).Single(e => e.Id == itemId);` If that leads to an NRE then its a problem with the data, not your code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look to turn off lazy loading on places that seem to get more errors than others. But what could make the exact same query with exact same data & exact same code work great for 3 weeks, then start crashing part of the time for 24ish hours or until we reset IIS?

Comment: @Alexey usually stack trace isn't helpful. MVC controller actions, then our model, business layer, data access, etc. Sometimes we do get exception like edited above.

Comment: Are you using the same context instance from multiple threads (e.g. by not awaiting tasks)?

Comment: @Pawel No, we shouldn't be, but suppose possibly could be in some dark corner of the application.

Comment: DbContext/ObjectContext is not thread safe and you could/would see weird crashes and data inconsistencies. They would be random.